# I can't save my Image (mid blend) to file?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've tried looking at the Oracle advice on Writing/Saving an image but nothing I do works. I have a start button that starts the blend of 2 images from one to another. Then a stop button to stop the blend midway (or wherever you want) then I have a saveImage button and would like it capture the image in it's current state and save it to file. But how ? here's the code from the Frame.java

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

class Frame extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Image MeSmaller1;
private Image MeSmaller2;
protected Timer timer;
private float alpha;

JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel();
static JButton btnStartBlend = new JButton("Start Blend");
static JButton btnStopBlend = new JButton("Stop Blend");
static JButton saveImage = new JButton("Save Image To File");

public Frame() {

    loadImages();
    initTimer();

    pnlButton.add(btnStartBlend);
    this.add(pnlButton);
    pnlButton.add(btnStopBlend);
    this.add(pnlButton);
    pnlButton.add(saveImage);
    this.add(pnlButton);

    addListeners();
 }
    // start button actionlistener
 public void addListeners() {
    btnStartBlend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            initTimer();
            timer.start();

            System.out.println("Timer started");
        }
    });
    // stop button actionlistener
    btnStopBlend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // initTimer();
            timer.stop();

            System.out.println("Timer stopped");
        }
    });
    // Save button actionlistener
    saveImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            System.out.println("Save image clicked");
        }
    });
}

private void loadImages() {
    MeSmaller1 = new ImageIcon("MeSmaller1.jpg").getImage();
    MeSmaller2 = new ImageIcon("MeSmaller2.jpg").getImage();
 }

 public void initTimer() {

    timer = new Timer(1000, this);
    timer.start();
    timer.stop();
    alpha = 1f;
 }

 private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2Dim = (Graphics2D) g;
    // below sets the size of picture
    BufferedImage buffImage = new BufferedImage(400, 600,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);


    Graphics2D gBuffI = buffImage.createGraphics();
    AlphaComposite aComp = AlphaComposite.getInstance(
            AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha);
    // decides where images are drawn in JFrame
    gBuffI.drawImage(MeSmaller1, 28, 55, null);
    gBuffI.setComposite(aComp);
    gBuffI.drawImage(MeSmaller2, 30, 48, null);
    g2Dim.drawImage(buffImage, 10, 10, null);
 }

 public static void saveToFile(BufferedImage img) {


 }
 @Override

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    doDrawing(g);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    alpha -= 0.1;
    if (alpha <= 0) {
        alpha = 0;
        timer.stop();
        System.out.println("Morph Finished please restart.");
    }
    repaint();
}
```

}

Can anyone help here it's just not working. There is also another class PictureMorph.java

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PictureMorph extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PictureMorph() {
    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Image Morph");
    setTitle("Facial Image Manipulation");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(new Frame());
    // below set Frame Size around image
    setSize(380, 470);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            PictureMorph picMorph = new PictureMorph();
            picMorph.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
 }
  }
```

And 3 classes (that I think could be redundant now actually?) called BtnStartBlendListener, BtnStopBlendListener, SaveImageListener that don't contain much code at all. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a JFileChooser and end up with a user friendly file selector, you may do this:

```
 private static Frame workFrame;

 public static Frame getWorkFrame() {
        return workFrame;
 }

 public static void setWorkFrame(Frame frame) {
    workFrame = frame;
 }
```

Then modify the save method the following way (the signature changes and also I have commented the code that uses the Scanner and replace it by the JFileChooser)

```
 public static void save(BufferedImage img, Frame frame) {

    //  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    //  System.out.println("Enter the file name: ");
    //  String fileFullPath = scan.next();
        String fileFullPath = getFileToSaveTo(frame);
        file = new File(fileFullPath);
        saveToFile(img, file);

}
```

Add the following method:

```
    public static String getFileToSaveTo(Frame frame) {
        JFileChooser fc=new JFileChooser();
          int returnVal=fc.showOpenDialog(frame);
          if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            return fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
          }
         else {
            return null;
          }
    }
```

In your main method have a call like `Frame.setWorkFrame(fr);`where fr is defined as `Frame fr = new Frame();`

This should make  it work with the JFileChooser. For example here is how I call the program in my main method

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame theFrame = new JFrame("Testing catess...");
        theFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        Frame fr = new Frame();
        theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        theFrame.add(fr, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        theFrame.setVisible(true);
        Frame.setWorkFrame(fr);
    }
```

It is working fine in my tests. Test and let me know if it works

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75538/discussion-on-answer-by-alainlompo-i-cant-save-my-image-mid-blend-to-file).

Comment: @bluefeet sorry about that, thank you for reminding us about this rule. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have left the saveToFile method empty, I assume that it is the major issue that you have.

For the saveToFile method you can use javax.imageio.ImageIO. I would suggest that you pass a File object parameter to your method so it knows where to save the image.

```
public static void saveToFile(BufferedImage img, File file) {
     String filename = file.getName();

     String suffix = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
     suffix = suffix.toLowerCase();

     if (suffix.equals("jpg") || suffix.equals("png")) {
         try { ImageIO.write(img, suffix, file); }
         catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
     }
    else {
        System.out.println("Error: filename must end in .jpg or .png");
    }

}
```

Hope this helps

**[EDIT]**

The File constructor allows you to instanciate the File object with a string representing the path to the file.

Example: assuming I want to save it in, let's say C:\Tests\image1.jpg, I would do this

```
File myFile = new File("C:\\Tests\\image1.jpg")
```

,where Tests represents an existing folder and image1.jpg is of course the name of the new file in which you will save your image.

So assume that img is a variable containing the reference to your BufferedImage object you would call the above method with

```
Frame.saveToFile(img, myFile);
```

where myFile is the above File object.

You can also add a static method such as the following one to get the user to specify the path to the file. I used Scanner to get it quick, but for a more user - friendly dialog, use a JFileChooser (examples are [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.swing.JFileChooser))

```
  public static void save(BufferedImage img) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the file name: ");
        String fileFullPath = scan.next();
        File file = new File(fileFullPath);
        saveToFile(img, file);

    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this looks great, how do I pass the File object parameter ? Also what would I put on the button saveImage ActionListener so that it connects with the button when pressed to initiate saving the file ? If you don't mind me asking for more help ... @alainlompo Your help is appreciated a lot. Caroline

Comment: @Catess76, in your saveImage ActionListener, add a call to Frame.saveToFile, passing in your BufferedImage reference variable and an instance of a File object similar to what I added. I hope this helps. And in this case if it solves your issue don't forget to up vote my answer or accept it

Comment: Here is the code as it looks now from the main class called Frame, I'm still trying to get it to saveImage once the save Image button is pressed. {link}(http://pastebin.com/hG6frc73) hope someone can help :-)

Comment: Thanks @alainlompo I'm trying this now :-)

Comment: I'm getting a lot of errors. I've added to my ActionListener this code:-     Frame.saveToFile(BufferedImage, File);   but getting loads of errors:-     Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Frame.saveToFile(Frame.java:111)
 at Frame$3.actionPerformed(Frame.java:75)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)

Comment: @catess you should use the same BufferedImage in your doDrawing method as in the saveToFile invocation method. I am trying to fix it

Comment: @Catess I solved a few issues and successfully test it. I could save an image and view it with windows image viewer. Will post the changes soon

Comment: @Catess, if it works for you, please accept my answer. See  explanations why here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

The issues you experienced are mostly related to the fact that you declared final some of the variables, notably the BufferedImage and the File object (which were null and since you make them final their values can't be changed)

I corrected these issues. Here is the whole code, except the imports statements which are the same as those you had in the link to your source code.

After you click on the save button, enter a full path to the file to save: example C:\test1.jpg in the console.

```
class Frame extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;  // Don't need to make this     final
    static File file = null;  // Don't need to make this final
    private Image MeSmaller1;
    private Image MeSmaller2;
    protected Timer timer;
    private float alpha;

    JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel();
    static JButton btnStartBlend = new JButton("Start Blend");
    static JButton btnStopBlend = new JButton("Stop Blend");
    static JButton saveImage = new JButton("Save Image To File");

    public Frame() {

            loadImages();
            initTimer();

            pnlButton.add(btnStartBlend);
            this.add(pnlButton);
            pnlButton.add(btnStopBlend);
            this.add(pnlButton);
            pnlButton.add(saveImage);
            this.add(pnlButton);

            addListeners();
    }
            // start button action listener
    public void addListeners() {
            btnStartBlend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            initTimer();
                            timer.start();

                            System.out.println("Timer started");
                    }
            });
            // stop button actionlistener
            btnStopBlend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            // initTimer();
                            timer.stop();

                            System.out.println("Timer stopped");
                    }
            });

            // Save button actionlistener
            saveImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent saveImage) {
                            save(bufferedImage);
                            System.out.println("Save image clicked");
                    }
            });
    }

    private void loadImages() {
            // I did my local test using
            //MeSmaller1 = new    ImageIcon("C:\\Tests\\Alain_Lompo.jpg").getImage();
            //MeSmaller2 = new    ImageIcon("C:\\Tests\\Alain_Lompo.jpg").getImage();

            MeSmaller1 = new ImageIcon("MeSmaller1.jpg").getImage();
            MeSmaller2 = new ImageIcon("MeSmaller2.jpg").getImage();
    }

    public void initTimer() {

            timer = new Timer(1000, this);
            timer.start();
            timer.stop();
            alpha = 1f;
    }

    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2Dim = (Graphics2D) g;
            // below sets the size of picture
            bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(400, 600,
                            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D gBuffI = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
            AlphaComposite aComp = AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                            AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha);
            // decides where images are drawn in JFrame
            gBuffI.drawImage(MeSmaller1, 28, 55, null);
            gBuffI.setComposite(aComp);
            gBuffI.drawImage(MeSmaller2, 30, 48, null);
            g2Dim.drawImage(bufferedImage, 10, 10, null);
    }



    public static void save(BufferedImage img) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the file name: ");
        String fileFullPath = scan.next();
        file = new File(fileFullPath);
        saveToFile(img, file);

    }

    public static void saveToFile(BufferedImage img, File file) {
         String filename = file.getName();

         String suffix = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
         suffix = suffix.toLowerCase();

         if (suffix.equals("jpg") || suffix.equals("png")) {
             try { ImageIO.write(img, suffix, file); }
             catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
         }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error: filename must end in .jpg or .png");
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            doDrawing(g);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            alpha -= 0.1;
            if (alpha <= 0) {
                    alpha = 0;
                    timer.stop();
                    System.out.println("Morph Finished please restart.");
            }
            repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame theFrame = new JFrame("Testing catess...");
        theFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        Frame fr = new Frame();
        theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        theFrame.add(fr, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        theFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi sorry I'm back, had to look for something for my son !! took ages.. I'll try it now @alainlompo :-) thanks

Comment: Hi, when I click save Image button the option to enter a filename appears but when I enter the filename it comes up with errors. However... I would quite like it if it brought up the save dialogue box so I could save to file I could choose. We're certainly getting much closer the the result I'm looking for now :-) appreciate your time very much. @alainlompo

Comment: Sure, I can set up the JFileChooser version in a few minutes

Comment: Just trying myself, it's not happening for me yet ... haha gotta love Java